# Stuck in importing libgdx project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I created a libgdx project in the Android studio projects folder. But when I select import gradle project -> build.gradle of the libgdx project in Android studio, it displays "Building projectname Gradle project info" and gets stuck here!

Comment: All I need to do is select my project folder in the `Import Gradle project dialogue`. I never select `build.gradle` directly. Other then that I'm not placing my libgdx projects in the AS project folder but that really should not matter. Maybe try to reinstall AS?

Answer (score 0):

It was not stuck but it was taking time to download the appropriate gradle. It takes a lot more time to download a grade through android studio than when you are downloading from the site. So if you get this problem :

1)check the gradle version its downloading (it would be shown at the bottom of android studio)

2)go to the site mentioned in the same bottom and download that gradle version

You would be good to go when you import the project the next time.